# Formulae for calculating line and circle intersection

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, systems-of-equations, circles

Very simple problem, yet I can't find a solution online and can't seem to keep track of the algebra.

Given $ax+by+c=0$ and $x^2+y^2=r^2$ ,  **Solve for x**

constraints: ($a,b,c =$ any real number) ($x,y,r$ any real number)
(there can obviously be $0,1,2$ solutions for $x$)

You have to plug it in and simplify it and end up doing quadratic formula, but I got lost after about a page of algebra. Now I'm pretty frustrated, please help me!

Thanks ya'll

Comment: Take a breath and then show your work. You might just be making a simple mistake that you’re not seeing, or need a small nudge to make progress from where you’re getting stuck.

Comment: A smart way to start would be to multiply the circle equation by $b^2$ to give $$b^2x^2+(by)^2=b^2r^2\ .$$ Then it will be easy to substitute $by=-c-ax$.

Comment: David, thank you for your help. I got to here which I verified is correct.... b^2x^2a+2cx=(b^2r^2-c^2)/a ... now what do I do? Quadratic formula seems a bit terse... I think there's an easier way

Answer (score 0):

I would first "solve" the linar equation
$$y= \frac{c-ax}{b}$$

Now we replace in the quadratic:

$$x^2 + (\frac{c-ax}{b})^2 = r^2$$

Compute that square:
$$x^2 + \frac{c^2}{b^2} - 2\frac{c-ax}{b^2} + \frac{a^2}{b^2}x^2 = r^2$$

Or, similarly
$$x^2 + \frac{c^2}{b^2} - 2\frac{c}{b^2}- 2\frac{a}{b^2}x + \frac{a^2}{b^2}x^2 = r^2$$

You can now group terms and solve the quadratic for $x$

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps if we try to eliminate fractions.

$$\begin{align}
ax+by+c &= 0\\
by &= -ax-c\\
by &= -(ax+c)\\
b^2y^2 &= (ax+c)^2\\
b^2y^2 &= a^2x^2+2acx+c^2\\
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
x^2+y^2&=r^2\\
y^2&=r^2-x^2\\
b^2y^2&=b^2r^2-b^2x^2\\
\end{align}$$

Can you take it from here?